# How to run ultimate thread group in Non gui mode of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are executing only first thread group while running the JMX file in Non gui mode with Ultimate Thread group.Is there any command to run Ultimate Thread group in Non Gui Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do you should put zero interations in first thread group and one or more interations in ultimate. You can edit intarations in tag *LoopController.loops* in your jmx file.